# Difference between selecting from built-in and user defined functions in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I am trying to understand the behavior of postgresql when it comes to selecting from scalar-valued functions that are either built-in, e.g. current_date and those that are defined by the user, particularly when it comes to aliasing. Take the following examples:

```
SELECT * FROM CURRENT_DATE AS x;
SELECT x FROM CURRENT_DATE AS x;
SELECT x.x FROM CURRENT_DATE AS x;
```

All of the above output the same thing, the current date in a column called "x".

Now define the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
    f (r OUT INTEGER)
AS $$
BEGIN
    r := 1;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then take the following examples:

```
SELECT * FROM f() AS x;
SELECT x FROM f() AS x;
SELECT r FROM f() AS x;
SELECT x.r FROM f() AS x;
SELECT x.x FROM f() AS x;
```

The first one outputs the value 1 in a column called "r". The second one outputs the value in a column called "x". The third and fourth ones output the value in a column called "r", same as the first. The fifth results in an error.

Why is the behavior different between the current_date and f functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that you gave the output parameter a name (`r`). If you don't do that, your function will behave like `current_date` in this respect.